# What is the Hamiltonian of the Lagrangian $L=-mc^2\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

What is the Hamiltonian of the Lagrangian $$L=-mc^2\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}.$$

So I know the answer is supposed to be $$H=\sqrt{m^2c^4 +p^2c^2}$$ but no matter how hard I try I can't substitute all the vs for ps.

$H=pv-L$, and $p=\gamma mv$, so if I substitute $v$ with $\dfrac{p}{\gamma m}$, the result is

$$H=\dfrac{p^2}{\gamma m}+\sqrt{m^2c^4-\dfrac{p^2c^2}{\gamma^2}}$$
and there's no way to insert the first term in the square root or get rid of the gamma (which depends on $v$).

Comment: First write down the Hamiltonian using *only* $v$. Next transform the result into a function of the only variable $p$. The result turns out to be  what you expected…

Comment: You can't replace $v$ with $p/\gamma m$ since $\gamma$ also depends on $v$. You have to solve the equation $p = m v / \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ for $v$.

Answer (score 8):

The $\gamma$ factor itself depends on $v$ (or $p$). So it is easier to keep everything in $v$ notation, writing the $\gamma$'s explicitly in terms of $v$'s. We can write
$$H = \gamma m v^2 + m c^2 \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} = \frac{m v^2}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} + m c^2 \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} = \frac{m c^2}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = \gamma mc^2. $$
Now to write this in your notation, we need to solve $\gamma$ as a function of $p$. Using $p = \gamma mv$ and $v = c \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\gamma^2}}$, we get
$$ p = m \gamma c \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\gamma^2}}.$$
Solving for $\gamma$ as a function of $p$, we obtain $\gamma = \sqrt{1 + \frac{p^2}{m^2 c^2}}$, so that indeed
$$ H = m c^2 \sqrt{1 + \frac{p^2}{m^2 c^2}}, $$
as expected.